# SharePoint Extranet Site Without Using FBA

Tags: extranet

How to create Extranet site on SharePoint 2010 standard edition but without using FBA. Without FBA can we enable the Intranet site as Extranet for external vendor purpose

Comment: what authentication method you want to use for extranet user?

Answer (score 2):

You have to follow these steps:

1. extend the web application to extranet zone
2. Configure the authentication i.e Anonymous
3. Create the DNS entry
4. Configure the AAM and IIS bindings and Loadbalancer(if any).
5. You also need to Configure the SSL if required.